# Rage Downvotes - How do we deal with them?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I was wondering about something: A friend who is quite active on Stack Overflow told me recently that if he feels offended by somebody, he just goes on their profile, opens a couple of answers or questions of them, and downvotes one after another.

I thought this cannot be possible. How does the site actually deal with this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An automated serial voting reversal script runs every day at around 03:00 UTC that reverses all votes (up/down) in a short period of time from one user on another user's posts.

The exact formula is not published (if it were, it would be abused to get the maximum number of upvotes/downvotes without a reversal), it seems that the fewest it takes to trigger a reversal is 3 votes within 5 minutes.

Reputation is refunded or removed accordingly (based on the type of vote), and it is as if the votes never happened.

However, if this behavior continues, the serial voter may find himself in [the penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: thank you! I haven't yet heard about this!